# How to append an HTML content in an existing HTML content

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have old HTML

```
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1><h2>North America</h2><h3><a id="_US_guidances/regulations"></a>US
    guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>Final Guidance: 25-May-2021: <a
            href="https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/emergency-use-authorization-vaccines-prevent-covid-19">Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent COVID-19: Guidance for Industry</a>
        <ol>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>def</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol><h2>Asia-Pacific </h2><h3><a id="_Australia_guidances/regulations"></a>Australia guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>Guidance: 04-Sep-2020: <a href="https://www.cortellis.com/intelligence/report/ri/regulatory/238041">Cortellis
        Report on In Vitro Diagnostics Regulatory Framework</a>
        <ol>
            <li>This Regulatory Summary is related to specific Regulation for In Vitro Diagnostics in Australia. It
                provides definitions and outlines legal framework from different points of view (manufacturers,
                importers and distributors). It gives information about Registration procedures, provides practical help
                on how to obtain its notification. This document also contains detailed information about fees, clinical
                trials, post-marketing vigilance system, labeling, pricing and reimbursement and advertising.
            </li>
            <li>Content Update on <strong>04-Sep-2020</strong>:
                <ol>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                    <li>three</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And this is the new HTML:

```
<h2>North America</h2><h3>US guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href=http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui> Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol><h2>Asia Pacific</h2><h3>Australia guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href=http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui> Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I need to append whats under US guidances and regulations in second HTML in the beginning of US Guidances/regulations of first HTML and same goes for Australia. Following is my code:

```
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_string_new, "html.parser")

    for li in soup2.select("h3 + ol > li"):
        h3_text = li.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
        h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3")

        if not h3_soup1:
            continue
        h3_soup1.find_next("ol").insert(0, li)
```

The problem is that it inserts everything under US like this

```
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1><h2>North America</h2><h3><a id="_US_guidances/regulations"></a>US
    guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui">
        Emergency Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui">
        Emergency Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Final Guidance: 25-May-2021: <a
            href="https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/emergency-use-authorization-vaccines-prevent-covid-19">Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent COVID-19: Guidance for Industry</a>
        <ol>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>def</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol><h2>Asia-Pacific </h2><h3><a id="_Australia_guidances/regulations"></a>Australia guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>Guidance: 04-Sep-2020: <a href="https://www.cortellis.com/intelligence/report/ri/regulatory/238041">Cortellis
        Report on In Vitro Diagnostics Regulatory Framework</a>
        <ol>
            <li>This Regulatory Summary is related to specific Regulation for In Vitro Diagnostics in Australia. It
                provides definitions and outlines legal framework from different points of view (manufacturers,
                importers and distributors). It gives information about Registration procedures, provides practical help
                on how to obtain its notification. This document also contains detailed information about fees, clinical
                trials, post-marketing vigilance system, labeling, pricing and reimbursement and advertising.
            </li>
            <li>Content Update on <strong>04-Sep-2020</strong>:
                <ol>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                    <li>three</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

I tried replacing this `h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3")` with this `h3_soup1 = soup1.find("h3", text = h3_text)` but it returns `None`.

Edit:

Expected output:

```
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1><h2>North America</h2><h3><a id="_US_guidances/regulations"></a>US
    guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui">
        Emergency Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>

    <li>Final Guidance: 25-May-2021: <a
            href="https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/emergency-use-authorization-vaccines-prevent-covid-19">Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent COVID-19: Guidance for Industry</a>
        <ol>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>def</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol><h2>Asia-Pacific </h2><h3><a id="_Australia_guidances/regulations"></a>Australia guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol>
    <li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui">
        Emergency Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
        <ol>
            <li> first list</li>
            <li> Second</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>Guidance: 04-Sep-2020: <a href="https://www.cortellis.com/intelligence/report/ri/regulatory/238041">Cortellis
        Report on In Vitro Diagnostics Regulatory Framework</a>
        <ol>
            <li>This Regulatory Summary is related to specific Regulation for In Vitro Diagnostics in Australia. It
                provides definitions and outlines legal framework from different points of view (manufacturers,
                importers and distributors). It gives information about Registration procedures, provides practical help
                on how to obtain its notification. This document also contains detailed information about fees, clinical
                trials, post-marketing vigilance system, labeling, pricing and reimbursement and advertising.
            </li>
            <li>Content Update on <strong>04-Sep-2020</strong>:
                <ol>
                    <li>One</li>
                    <li>Two</li>
                    <li>three</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please show us the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html_string, "html.parser")
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_string_new, "html.parser")


def fn(txt, tag):
    if tag.name != "h3":
        return
    t = re.sub(r"\s{2,}", " ", tag.get_text(strip=True))
    return txt in t


for li in soup2.select("h3 + ol > li"):
    h3_text = li.find_previous("h3").get_text(strip=True)
    h3_soup1 = soup1.find(lambda t: fn(h3_text, t))
    if not h3_soup1:
        continue
    h3_soup1.find_next("ol").insert(0, li)


print(soup1)
```

Prints:

```html
<h1>Health Authority Updates</h1><h2>North America</h2><h3><a id="_US_guidances/regulations"></a>US
    guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol><li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui"> Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
<ol>
<li> first list</li>
<li> Second</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>Final Guidance: 25-May-2021: <a href="https://www.fda.gov/regulatory-information/search-fda-guidance-documents/emergency-use-authorization-vaccines-prevent-covid-19">Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent COVID-19: Guidance for Industry</a>
<ol>
<li>abc</li>
<li>def</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol><h2>Asia-Pacific </h2><h3><a id="_Australia_guidances/regulations"></a>Australia guidances/regulations</h3>
<ol><li>2021-06-22:<a href="http://www.minsa.gob.pa/noticia/arranca-esperado-proceso-de-vacunacion-en-chiriqui"> Emergency
        Use Authorization for Vaccines to Prevent weweCOVID-19: Guidance for Industry 22</a>
<ol>
<li> first list</li>
<li> Second</li>
</ol>
</li>
<li>Guidance: 04-Sep-2020: <a href="https://www.cortellis.com/intelligence/report/ri/regulatory/238041">Cortellis
        Report on In Vitro Diagnostics Regulatory Framework</a>
<ol>
<li>This Regulatory Summary is related to specific Regulation for In Vitro Diagnostics in Australia. It
                provides definitions and outlines legal framework from different points of view (manufacturers,
                importers and distributors). It gives information about Registration procedures, provides practical help
                on how to obtain its notification. This document also contains detailed information about fees, clinical
                trials, post-marketing vigilance system, labeling, pricing and reimbursement and advertising.
            </li>
<li>Content Update on <strong>04-Sep-2020</strong>:
                <ol>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please explain your logic. Why wasn't soup.find("h3", text = ..) working

Comment: @hannahmontanna If you look in `soup1`, the text inside `<h3>` is split into multiple newlines. So to compare the `<h3>` text from soup2, I need to first remove these newlines. It's easier to do in explicit function.